# Oozie Client Java Api Kereberos Authentication Error

Tags: java, kerberos, oozie

I'm using Oozie Java Client Api to read the Job metadata from Oozie. I'm getting the follwing error.

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","/user/abc/conf/jaas.conf");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","/user/abc/conf/krb5.conf");
AuthOozieClient wc = new AuthOozieClient(OOZIE_SERVER_URL.toString());
wc.setDebugMode(1);
Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();
if(System.getenv("HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION")!=null){
conf.setProperty("mapreduce.job.credentials.binary",System.getenv("HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION"));   
}
String yarnAppId = wc.getWorkflowActionInfo(wfActionId).getExternalId();
```

Getting the Following Error:
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception, IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 1. Exception = Could not authenticate, GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)

Comment: You need to setup a keytab file, and make sure klist is showing a valid token for your user.

Comment: Created the keytab file. Do I need to keep it in all the datanodes or in HDFS folder?

Comment: On the edge node. That message means the workflow didn't start because your application id doesn't have a valid kerberos session.

Comment: This error message does not make sense -- unless you are running that Java code **inside** an Oozie action, and it crashes the action. So, where do you run that Java code, exactly? And where did you find that code snippet? And why do you mess with `HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION` -- which, again, would make sense inside an Oozie action, but is 100% irrelevant when contacting the Oozie web service??

Comment: BTW, what kind of JAAS config did you stuff in that `jaas.conf`? Where did you find the model for that low-level config *(I'm curious because the Oozie documentation is rather rudimentary and often confusing)*

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter This was the snippet I was referring to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229736/oozie-java-api-submit-job-kerberos-authentication-error
And the HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION is just used for testing puropose.

Comment: OK, so again, where do you run that Java code? *(a)* on an Edge Node, *(b)* inside an Oozie Java action, *(c)* somewhere else (e.g. inside an IDE on your laptop)?

Comment: Inside an Oozie Java Action.

Comment: Resolved. Created userPrincipal and keytab file. Passed it to the Java code. Used UserGroupInformation for the secure login using keytab and principal and able to access oozie.

Comment: @ArunSundar could you post code snippet of how your solution worked?